# Retrieving datasource properties like name, connection using datasource jndi in wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jndi

Is there any method provided by wildfly to retrieve the datasource properties like name,connection URL from the datasource jndi?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution could be to

1. inject a datasource into a managed Bean:

   @Resource(mappedName="java:/jdbc/mydatasource")
   private static DataSource ds;
2. Open (for a short time) a connection on the ds
3. Read the various metadata available on the obtained connection (cfr https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html); namely: `getUserName()`, `getUrl()`, ...
4. close the connection

Other useful info:
https://www.baeldung.com/jdbc-database-metadata

Beware that the available metadata are dependant of the driver implementation !